# RabbitMQ - ReQueue the Message in C#

Tags: rabbitmq

please guide me how to requeue and reprocess the messages by the consumer. my objective is to requeue the message if there is an error in the message and then consumer will try to reconsume again. lets assume that if i send messahe to database, and will return an error.in this case i can be able to send the message for requeing and reprocessing.

if i am rejecting the message, it keeps processing the same and not going to next message. in my case i am rejecting 4, but it not moving forward to process the 5.

1 2 3 4 4 4 4

consumer.Received += (sender, args) => {

```
//Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Wait();

var body = args.Body.ToArray();
var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body);


//send message to database at this level
Console.WriteLine($"Message received by receiver1: {message}");

if (Convert.ToInt32(message) == 4)
{
    channel.BasicReject(args.DeliveryTag,true);

}
else
{
    channel.BasicAck(args.DeliveryTag, false);
}
```

};

Answer (score 0):

You send requeue=true in the basicReject without limit the retry counts, so the message will be requeued nonstop.

If you are using a quorum queue, you can limit the retry count by adding `x-delivery-limit` argument to the queue like so

```cs
 var queueArgs = new Dictionary<string, object>();
 queueArgs.Add("x-delivery-limit", QUEUE_DELIVERY_COUNT);

  _channel.QueueDeclare(queueName, durable, false, false, queueArgs);
```

If you use a classic queue or you want to implement a full retry mechanism including dead letter you can read the following article: [RabbitMQ Retries](https://engineering.nanit.com/rabbitmq-retries-the-full-story-ca4cc6c5b493)